# Probability: What is probability of a student solving at least x questions from n randomly chosen questions?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, monte-carlo

Out of a pool of 50 questions, 7 random questions are selected for the exam. If a student prepares a total of 16 questions perfectly, what is the probability that he can solve at least one of the 7 random questions.  My solution is :

- Number of possible question combinations:**C(50,7)**
- Combinations where no prepared question occurs:**C(34,7)**

P(no questions solved) : **C(34,7)/C(50,7)**

P(atleast one question) : **1 - (C(34,7)/C(50,7))**

But I am not sure if this approach is correct. In addition, I have to also prepare a script with monte carlo method to verify it empirically. Which I am not sure how to proceed with.

Comment: Your "P(no questions solved)" is greater than 1.

Comment: Consider the reciprocal of the Math expression for the probability of no questions solved, that is expressed in your posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prob misses the first question is 34/50.  Prob. missing second (after missing first) is 33/49, etc. so prob. missing all seven is $Q=(34\times 33\times ...\times 28)/(50\times 49 ...\times 44)$  The desired prob. is $P=1-Q$.  Your answer for P(no questions) should be the reciprocal of your statement.

Comment: Thanks .This is also what I predicted.

Comment: Any idea of how to do a Monte Carlo for this problem?

Comment: @flash  Fill urn with 34 black balls and 16 white balls.  Pick out 7 balls without replacement.  This can be simulated on computer.